# How to read POST requests in Lua?

Tags: post, nginx, lua, telegram-bot

I have this Telegram bot written in Lua that I am doing as a hobby for a language network. And I have been reading new messages via the getUpdates API call all the time. Now I want to rewrite it to use webhooks, but I have no experience with that whatsoever. I have googled but didn't find anything certain. I kinda feel that WSAPI is the library to use, but I am not sure. Moreover, I am not really sure I need any special library just for reading POST requests (which is all that the Telegram bot API uses). I tried using sockets:

```
socket = require 'socket'
server = assert(socket.bind("*", 9000))

function read(client, pattern, prefix)
  local data, emsg, partial = client:receive(pattern, prefix)
  if data then
    return data
  end
  if partial and #partial > 0 then
    return partial
  end
  return nil, emsg
end

while true do
  local client = server:accept()
  client:settimeout(3)
  local msg, err = read(client, '*a')

  if not err then
    print(msg)
    client:close()
  end
end
```

The `print(msg)` here gives me the full POST request including headers, which I am probably able to parse (the body is supposed to always be a JSON). I am not really that familiar with HTTP requests though and I'm not sure I can just throw away everything that goes before the first `{`.

My setup is Lua 5.2, Ubuntu x64 16.04 and Nginx. What I need to do is to receive and read POST requests, nothing more.

TL;DR: is it okay to parse the POST request I receive from the code above or am I missing something, like a library that'd make my life easier?

Thanks!

Comment: asking for library recommendations is considered off-topic. your question might be downvoted and/or closed. I am sure websearch will give you enough hints where to start. if you think wsapi is the way to go, go that way for a few steps and see if you're right. worst case you got yourself some experience in another library. what about this link that jumps right in your face when you google "lua post request"?  
 http://forum.ptokax.org/index.php?topic=8130.0

Comment: I have seen that link, but I don't need to send either POST or GET requests and I didn't find that useful. 

Okay, thanks for the comment, I'll update my question to maybe sound a bit more on-topic.

Comment: You need to spawn a server. I recommend using existing ones like open resty, lor, etc